# How to disable view bob in Black Mesa?

Tags: black-mesa

I'm playing Black Mesa. How can I disable view bob (as happens when sidestepping)? I find it gives me motion sickness.

I can't see any option in the menu.

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's a console variable?

Comment: Is this the Steam version? http://store.steampowered.com/app/362890/

Comment: As far as I can tell from Black Mesa's forums, even though they refer to an outdated version, View Roll is the thing you're looking to change. Try setting it to 0, and let me know if that works. If it does, I'll craft an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Steam version, open **Options > Game** and set **View Roll** to 0 to disable view bobbing.

[image: Game options in Steam version]

In the free mod version, open **Options > Black Mesa** and set **View Roll** to 0.

[image: Game options in mod version]

(The mod version I found has an option labeled *Disable View Bob*, but it doesn't seem to work)

Answer (score 13):

Console `cl_view_roll 0` got rid of view bob when sidestepping.

Comment: Also available as the "View Roll" slider in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: @Kroltan Thanks I was looking for a checkbox rather than a slider.